# Realm SyncUser.login does not return syncUser.current in Swift

Tags: swift, realm

I am logging the user into the global realm. For this I am using the SyncUser.login function provided in realm docs but none of the code in the completion handler runs and so my app keeps crashing as SyncUser.current == nil. 
This is the code that's not working:

```
SyncUser.logIn(with: .anonymous(), server: URL(string: "https://centralized-soft-chips.us1.cloud.realm.io")!) {
                (user, err) in
                if let _ = user {
                    // User is logged in
                    print("SUCCESS")
                } else if let error = err {
                    print("Error")
                    fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
```

Has anyone ran into this problem or can they recreate it?

Comment: Do you have anonymous auth turned on in the cloud portal?

Answer (score 1):

This is a *total* guess because your code works for me.

I think what's happening is you have two users authenticated at the same time. This happens to us during development because they app will crash and leave a user authenticated and then when we make a change and re-run, we may authenticate another user etc etc.

When there is more than one auth'd user, calling SyncUser.current will crash.

First, I would flip the error checking around like this to catch any fatal type errors first, returning if that happens.

```
SyncUser.logIn(with: creds, server: Constants.AUTH_URL) { user, err in
    if let err = err {
        print(err.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
```

Try that and see if that prints any errors to console.

I don't know where you login code is called from but here's what we have in place. If the app starts and there is more than one user auth'd from this device, we just log them all out and then proceed to the login

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()

    let count = SyncUser.all.count
    if count > 1 {
        for userDict in SyncUser.all {
            let user = userDict.value as! SyncUser
            user.logOut()
        }
    }

    if let _ = SyncUser.current {
        print("user already logged in")
        self.finishLogin()
    } else {
        print("logging in a user")
        self.handleLoginAction()
    }
}
```

The *SyncUser.all* is a dictionary of all valid, logged-in user identities corresponding to their SyncUser objects.

Again, this is a total guess - please post comments if any further information comes to light and I will update (or delete) the answer accordingly.